# What are the differences among pagerank, pagerank_numpy and pagerank_scipy in NetworkX?

Tags: networkx, difference, pagerank

I checked the descriptions of 
[`pagerank`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank.html),
[`pagerank_numpy`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank_numpy.html#networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank_numpy) and
[`pagerank_scipy`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank_scipy.html#networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank_scipy)
from [NetworkX documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). I can't see the difference.

```
pagerank(G, alpha=0.85, personalization=None, max_iter=100, tol=1e-06, nstart=None, weight='weight', dangling=None)

pagerank_numpy(G, alpha=0.85, personalization=None, weight='weight', dangling=None)

pagerank_scipy(G, alpha=0.85, personalization=None, max_iter=100, tol=1e-06, weight='weight', dangling=None)
```

What are the differences among them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all compute the same thing but with slightly different methods to compute the largest eigenvalue/eigenvector (the pagerank scores).

- `pagerank` is a pure-Python implementation
- `pagerank_numpy` uses the dense linear algebra subpackage of numpy
- `pagerank_scipy` uses the sparse linear algebra subpackage of scipy

The `pagerank_scipy` implementation should be fastest and use the least memory for large graphs.